# Testing JMS in Java EE Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jboss-arquillian

Scenario: I have JMS topic and it's consumer. I want to write an integration test that test this case:

- given - some message
- when - call a method that send a message to topic
- then - verify if method in consumer has been called once.

Is there a way to do this. eg. with Arquillian?

Answer (score 0):

I built ejb-cdi-unit, an extension to cdi-unit that addresses such issues.
See the following examples:

- [example1](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/tree/master/examples/ex5-asyncconsumedjms1)
- [example2](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/tree/master/examples/ex5-asyncconsumedjms2)

The test shows a configuration with 2 Mdbs and 1 Messagecreator. The tests show how the messages are created and processed until a remoteinterface returns a callback which itself produces internally a message that is processed. 
The module discovers Queues, Topics, Mdbs, and ConnectionFactories and wires them together using an in-memory JMS-Implementation.

And yes there is a way to do this in Arquillian with wildfly, there is a [test](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/blob/master/ejb-cdi-unit-arq/src/test/java/ejbcdiunit/WildflyArquillianMdbTest.java) but you need to configure and start a full ejb-server